# How to prevent form input fields from clearing when button is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple form that allows users to enter multiple first and last names if they have had different names. The form initially loads with only one entry each for first and last name. To add more input fields for their name, they click a button which calls this function:

TS CODE

```
 addName(){
   this.person.fullName.push({ firstName : "", lastName : ""});
 }
```

This adds the input fields as intended but also clears the user's input from the previous fields. How can I prevent user input from being cleared when more input fields are added dynamically?

HTML code

Button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" id="addName" (click)="addName()">More Names</button>
```

MORE HTML

```
<div class="card-body"  *ngFor="let index of 
   person['fullName']'; trackBy : trackByName'">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="person.id" placeholder="Given name"
                      required
                      [(ngModel)]="index.firstName" name="firstName"
                      #firstName="ngModel">
```

Comment: Are you using "angular" ("angular" version 2 or higher) or "angularjs"?

Comment: @spyro Angular. not angularjs